# Create a valid JSON using Jackson that contains an array and a custom field

Tags: java, json, jackson

My code below to generate a JSON using Jackson, is fine as far as the data is concerned, but its not a JSON

The generated JSON doesnt pass [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/), because its got quotes around the square brackets and quotes around commas. It also backslashes which I hacked out of it - but Im pretty sure there's something wrong with what Im doing below

Here is what I'm trying to do:

The JSON is supposed to look  as follows  (with the exception of the `skip` field which I have added here to highlight that it will be omitted from the Object when serialized):

```
{
    "users": [{
        "foo": "abc1",
        "bar": "def1",
        "skip": "this field is skipped"
    }, {
        "foo": "abc2",
        "bar": "def2",
        "skip": "this field is skipped"
    }],
    "uri": "/users"
}
```

The users Key is an array of users - 2 elements shown above. The skip field shouldnt be part of the final json, but its part of each 'user' object

The URI field is added

My code is below. It successfully skips the 'skip' field and it successfully builds a String that is almost a JSON if the weird formatting is eliminated. But I admit this code is horrid and it can be better (although I dont know how since Im new to this)

What is the weird formatting you ask?

1. backslashes (that you can see i have eliminated using hackey regex)
2. Quotes around [ and ]
3. Quotes around , (commas)

Code:

```
get("/users", (request, response) -> {
    //this is the array of objects
    Object[] allUsers = listenUp.get_all_users();

    //Ignore this field per ListenUpUser object
    String[] ignorableFieldNames = { "skip" };

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    mapper.addMixIn(Object.class, PropertyFilterMixIn.class);
    FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
            .addFilter("filter properties by name",
                    SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(
                            ignorableFieldNames));
    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(filters);

    ArrayNode array = mapper.createArrayNode();

    for(int i = 0; i < allUsers.length; i++) {
        array.add(writer.writeValueAsString(allUsers[i]));
    }

    JsonNodeFactory nodeFactory = JsonNodeFactory.instance;
    ObjectNode child = mapper.createObjectNode();
    child.put("users", array.toString());
    child.put("uri", "/users");
    response.status(200);
    response.type("application/json");
    String a = child.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", "");
    return a;
});
```

This has been defined at the top of the file (for the skip field logic)

```
@JsonFilter("filter properties by name")
class PropertyFilterMixIn {}
```

Comment: If you don't want quotes around the list, then why are you doing `child.put("users", array.toString());`? Just put `array`, not the string of it

Comment: Yup I tried that and the result is even more bizzare: http://pastebin.com/fAfUcv92

Comment: If you are using Jackson, I don't see why you are manually creating a JsonObject for you class. Just use the serialization feature of Jackson

Comment: Im not following - can you point out what Im doing manually and what I can improve?

Comment: When you create an array or object node from the mapper, you are manually creating JSON. Please see http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Comment: Ok, thats helpful, but its still not clear how I can build a JSON array, after I have used a mapper to serialize each object - or can the mapper build an entire JSON array when provided a Java Array, while also maintaining the skip field that should be omitted? and If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `Hashmap<String, Object>`. Jackson will understand how to apply filter to the `Object` in array and will just skip any other object(String/array) it finds. Here is demo, that works for me:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFilter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.FilterProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleFilterProvider;
import org.json.JSONException;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class test12 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JSONException {
        Object[] allUsers = get_all_users();

        String[] ignorableFieldNames = {"skip"};

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        mapper.addMixIn(Object.class, PropertyFilterMixIn.class);
        FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider()
                .addFilter("filter properties by name",
                        SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept(
                                ignorableFieldNames));
        mapper.setFilterProvider(filters);

        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("users", allUsers);
        map.put("uri", "/users");
        String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);

        System.out.println(result);
    }

    @JsonFilter("filter properties by name")
    public static class PropertyFilterMixIn {
    }

    private static Object[] get_all_users() {
        User user1 = new User();
        user1.foo = "abc1";
        user1.bar = "def1";
        user1.skip = "this field is skipped";
        User user2 = new User();
        user2.foo = "abc2";
        user2.bar = "def2";
        user2.skip = "this field is skipped";
        return new Object[]{user1, user2};
    }

    public static class User {
        public String foo;
        public String bar;
        public String skip;
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
{
  "users" : [ {
    "foo" : "abc1",
    "bar" : "def1"
  }, {
    "foo" : "abc2",
    "bar" : "def2"
  } ],
  "uri" : "/users"
}
```

Comment: This is it! Thanks a ton!